# How to uncompress .7z files in elixir/erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am working on a problem which requires my system to uncompress .7z files in elixir/erlang.

Is there any such library that can uncompress .7z file in erlang or elixir? Or any method to do the same?

TIA :)

Comment: I've never done something like that but my guess would be that you'd have to call some system utility to do that.

Comment: What OS are you working on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the best and simplest way for doing it is by running the right system command to uncompress the file.
You can do this using [`os:cmd/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1):

In case you just want to uncompress to the working directory, just run this command:

```
os:cmd("7za x File.7z").
```

For more information about how to use 7z in command line see [this](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/index.htm) or [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

**Note:** You just need to make sure you have the right [7z utility](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) according to your OS.

Comment: The idea of using system command did work for me. However, the command did not worked exactly like that on my elixir system. System.cmd("7z",["e","test_file.7z"]) worked, and I had installed p7zip-full on my ubuntu for uncompressing the 7zip files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out this Erlang module as well.  http://erlang.org/doc/man/zip.html

Comment: I did, but it does have some limitations and it doesn't work on 7z files.